# Add custom labels using Go-Grpc-Prometheus

Tags: go, grpc, prometheus

we have gRPC service in GoLang. To measure application metrics we would like use existed library https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus.

However we need add a custom label to metrics, but it seems that library implementations does not allow it. Can you confirm it, or I'm out, and there is way **how to add a custom labels** into them? Many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus/blob/ae0d8660c5f2108ca70a3776dbe0fb53cf79f1da/metric_options.go#L20 and https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus/blob/ae0d8660c5f2108ca70a3776dbe0fb53cf79f1da/server_metrics.go#L27 same here https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus/blob/ae0d8660c5f2108ca70a3776dbe0fb53cf79f1da/client_metrics.go#L38 nop ?

Comment: do you use the default prometheus config file to scrape your gRPC service? You can add your curtom label there

Comment: We leave these requirements. There is no way to add a custom label to go-grpc-prometheus. You can add constant label as it mentioned by  mh-cbon, or fork go-grpc-prometheus and change it.